# How do I Mock SpringApplication.run

Tags: mockito, spring-batch, powermock

I have a File handler for Spring Batch that I want to test.

`SpringApplication.run()` is a static method for which I would like to verify the arguments passed to it.

Does this mean I need to go down the PowerMock path or is there something in the SpringFramework that will enable me to test this?

```
public File handleFile(File file) {

    // Start the Batch Process and set the inputFile parameter
    String[] args = {"--inputFile=" + file.getAbsolutePath()};
    SpringApplication.run(InitialFileBatchApplication.class, args);

    return null;
}
```

My test class has the following annotations which don't seem to be working:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@PrepareForTest(SpringApplication.class)
```

What am I missing?

The exception getting thrown is:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication. Reason: cannot find
>   org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment

This occurs when the `@PrepareForTest(SpringApplication.class)` is processed. I'm testing a Spring Batch application so there is no web environment and I've also added.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.NONE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue due to the exception that I was having was due to a missing entry in the pom.xml, which frustrates me a bit with the SpringFramework since I'm working only in a batch application and have no web or servlet components whatsoever in this test.  The missing pom entry was.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The other spring dependecies that I had were

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

In order to test this, I did take the approach of PowerMock with externalizing some of the methods so that I could test them and even though I'm testing with a Spring Application, I was able to exclude the SpringRunner that loads the context to simplify this test.  Below is my implementation class as well as the test class that tested it.

```
import java.io.File;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

public class InitialFileInputFileHandler {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InitialFileInputFileHandler.class);

    /**
     * Handles the Initial Client files that get put into the input directory that match the pattern
     * defined in initialFileListenerApplicationContext.xml
     * @param file - The file
     * @return
     */

    public File handleFile(File file) {

        logger.info("Got the Initial Client file: " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " start Batch Processing");

        // Start the Batch Process and set the inputFile parameter
        String[] args = buildArguments(file);

        SpringApplication.run(InitialFileBatchApplication.class, args);

        // Whatever we return is written to the outbound-channel-adapter.  
        // Returning null will not write anything out and we do not need an outbound-channel-adapter
        return null;
    }

    protected String[] buildArguments(File file) {
    String[] args = {"--inputFile=" + file.getAbsolutePath()};
    return args;
    }
}
```

And here's the test class

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.*;

import java.io.File;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

// This test class must test static methods.  One way to do that is with PowerMock.

// Testing with static methods so we have to run with the PowerMockRunner.
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
// The static method that we want to test is in the SpringApplication class so 
// by using PowerMock we have to prepare this class for testing.
@PrepareForTest({SpringApplication.class})

// If you wanted to load a SpringContext you'd have to include the SpringRunner.
// Since our Runner is PowerMockRunner, we still have to setup the spring context, so
// you setup the SpringRunner as the delegate.
//@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class)
public class InitialFileInputFileHandlerTest {

    // Setup a mockFile so that I can specify what comes back from the getAbsolutiePath method
    // without actually to have a file on the file system.
    @Mock File mockFile;

    private InitialFileInputFileHandler handler;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    handler = new InitialFileInputFileHandler();
    org.mockito.Mockito.when( mockFile.getAbsolutePath() ).thenReturn("src/input/fooFile.txt");
    }

    @Test 
    public void testBuildArguments(){
    String[] args = handler.buildArguments(mockFile);
    assertThat( args[0], equalTo("--inputFile=src/input/fooFile.txt") );
    }

    @Test
    public void testHandleFile() throws Exception {
    // Tell PowerMockito to keep track of my static method calls in the SpringApplication class
    PowerMockito.mockStatic( SpringApplication.class );

    // What I expect the argument to be
    String[] args = {"--inputFile=src/input/fooFile.txt"};

    // Call the actual method
    handler.handleFile(mockFile);

    // Have to call verifyStatic since its a static method.
    PowerMockito.verifyStatic();

    // One of a few possibilities to test the execution of the static method.
    //SpringApplication.run( InitialFileBatchApplication.class, args);
    //SpringApplication.run( Mockito.any(InitialFileBatchApplication.class), eq(args[0]));
    SpringApplication.run( Mockito.any(Object.class), eq(args[0]));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I share your dislike for PowerMock, the first answer is unfortunately: the method that you have written right now - **yes** that can only be tested using PowerMock.

So, if you want to test **that** method; you have to use PowerMock. Or you take the minimal risk ... and simply don't test it.

Beyond that: I recommend to put that method into some interface; you simply want to *prevent* that this static call gives you trouble when you start testing other methods that want to call `handleFile()` - then you want to be able to mock that call; to prevent that static call inside to happen.

Answer (score 0):

1.if you want to verify `args` in your tests, you need to return it to caller code of method `handleFile(file)` and currently you are doing - `return null;` , instead you should return args ( if method signature can be changed ).

I have assumed that `handleFile` method is in `InitialFileBatchApplication` class.

```
@Test
    public void testHandleFile() {
        File file = new File("ABC");
        String[] response = new InitialFileBatchApplication().handleFile(file);

        //Verify response here
    }
```

Above will actually kick off your job.

2.If you wish to mock - `SpringApplication.run` as it is , PowerMock is the way to go. You should indicate in question as what error you are getting with current set up.

3.Mockito is inbuilt in Spring Test now so if you can refactor your code to have a non - static method call the static method then you can mock non - static method and that will eventually mock your static call. `@MockBean` annotation is part of Spring Test.

4.If Mocking `SpringApplication.run` in spring batch is equivalent to **not running the job** but simply initializing the context then purpose can be achieved by saying , `spring.batch.job.enabled=false`  in `application.properties`. Only that your unit tests will have to wait for real call to - `SpringApplication.run` to complete but job will not kick off.

Code refactoring is always encouraged to make your code unit testable in addition to functionally being correct so don't hesitate to refactor to overcome framework limitations.

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Idealling mocking the SpringApplication.run is what I want to do, but that doesn't mean that I should be architecturing this class differently so that its testable.  From my test class, I now have the following annotations, but Still getting the exception above.  

    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest(SpringApplication.class)
    @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.NONE)
@TestPropertySource(properties={"spring.batch.job.enabled=false"})